# How would I export perl subroutines while using the use Somedir::MyModule syntax?

Tags: perl, module, namespaces

I was wondering what it is I'm doing wrong in my code. I used @EXPORT in my module so that when I use it, the functions will be available in my user space. This does not seem to work if I do a use with a Directory in front of it. use SomeDir::MyModule appears to ignore the subroutines I placed in @EXPORT.  I know about namespace being polluted and that we should prefix the exported functions with the namespace like MyModule::myfunction and that does work, but I thought using @EXPORT should export those for you automatically. *Please forgive me if my terminology is off*

Here is my module and I have it in a directory like   bin/SomeDir/MyModule.pm
NOTE: my example is using a folder named MyPackage and my pm is named Math.pm

```
package Math;
use strict;
use warnings;
print "-PERL- Loading Package: ". __PACKAGE__ . "\n";
use FindBin qw($RealBin $RealScript);
use Exporter;
our @ISA   = qw(Exporter);
# Symbols (subs or vars) to export by default 
our @EXPORT    = qw(addition);
# Symbols to export by request
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(subtraction);

sub addition($$) {
    my $num1 = shift;
    my $num2 = shift;
    return $num1 + $num2;
}

sub subtraction($$) {
    my $num1 = shift;
    my $num2 = shift;
    return $num1 - $num2;
}
 
1;
```

And here is the perl script that is trying to make use of the addition() subroutine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($RealBin $RealScript);
use lib "$RealBin/./";

use MyPackage::Math ;

my $result = addition(10, 10); # This fails 
print("addition result is $result\n");

$result = Math::subtraction(10, 10); # This works of course
print("subtraction result is $result\n");
```

What I'm asking about here is the 'addition()' call that I'm making. I thought that because my Math.pm uses @EXPORT for "addition", that when I 'use' that module the 'addition' subroutine would automatically be exported and available to me. It does not appear to be so. Here is the error I see when I try to run my script.

> -PERL- Loading Package: Math Undefined subroutine &main::addition called at ./script.pl line 10.

Comment: You have `use MyPackage::Math`, but your module source has `package Math;`, not `package MyPackage::Math;`...

Comment: Thank you Shawn. That resolves my issue.

Comment: (You also need to use `MyPackage::Math::subtraction(10, 10)` after changing the package name)